Apache Camel MockEndpoint: how to assert (multiple) parts of received body
I have a (Quarkus) integration test like this:
@QuarkusTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class MyTest extends CamelQuarkusTestSupport {

    @EndpointInject("mock:my-mock")
    MockEndpoint myMockEndpoint;

    @Override
    protected void doAfterConstruct() throws Exception {
        adviceWith(context, "my-route", route -> route.weaveById("my-endpoint")
            .replace()
            .to("mock:my-mock"));
    }

    @Test
    void myTest() throws Exception {
        myMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        // How to assert (multiple) parts of received body?

        // Do testing...

        myMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

}

I know I can assert the entire body with:
myMockEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived("Entire body");

Now if the (XML) payload is actually bigger, I wonder how I can assert multiple parts of it? Something like:
myMockEndpoint.expectedBodyReceived() // returns AssertionClause
        .body()                       // returns MockValueBuilder
        .contains("Some part")        // returns Predicate
        .contains("Another part");    // not possible

However, chaining as above is not possible. Also, if I only have a single contains and end the expression/statement aferwards, the assertion is not taken into account. The test always passed, no matter what is passed to contains.
So, how can I assert multiple parts of the received body with Apache Camel's MockEndpoint?

You could try with expectedMessagesMatches and provide your own predicate(s).
https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-mock/4.7.0/org/apache/camel/component/mock/MockEndpoint.html#expectedMessagesMatches(org.apache.camel.Predicate...)
For example.
mockEndpoint.expectedMessagesMatches(new Predicate() {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
        String body = exchange.getMessage().getBody(String.class);
        return body.contains("Some part") && 
               body.contains("Another part");    
    }
});


You can also leverage some of the Camel built in predicates like xpath etc.
mockEndpoint.expectedMessagesMatches(XPathBuilder.xpath("/item[@price > 10.00]"));

